# jQuery full screen section slide left, slide right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, slide

I am playing with jquery recently and right now - trying to get animations to work.

Whole idea is basically a fullscreen slider. We have few sections with position absolute and height 100% of the document - in jquery we're playing with z-index. It's quite simply, but I can't figure out how to make a proper slide left and right animations. It's always breaking.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 var slideCount = $('.slide').length;

 $('button#next').on('click', function() {
  var slideActive = $('.slide.active');
  var nextSlide = slideActive.next('.slide');
  
  nextSlide.addClass('active').animate({
   'z-index' : '2',
   'left' : windowWidth
  },500);
  
  slideActive.removeClass('active');

 });

 

});;
```

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

body {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
}

nav {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2rem;
 right: 2rem;
 z-index: 99;
}

section {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
}

section#home {
 background-color: #2c3e50;
}

section#aboutMe {
 background-color: #e74c3c;
}

section#smthElse {
 background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <button id="prev">Back</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</nav>
<section id="home" class="slide active">
  <div class="container">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="aboutMe" class="slide">
  <div class="container">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="smthElse" class="slide">
  <div class="container">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Before that I tried just by adding class with css defined in .css and animating it (jquery ui) but effect was more or less the same.

All I want to achive is a simple slide functions of my sections. 
Example behaviour: http://codepen.io/jibbon/pen/BoisC

Also, I am not looking for ready solutions as I need as simple code as possible to learn and develop it in my way.

Thank you guys!

Comment: So, you are wanting to do this only with css3 animations?

Comment: No, I'am open for all options which include html/css/jquery even jquery ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that you can improve in your code to achieve what you want.

First, active class is set to a slide but isn't applied any special CSS rule, as you set `position: absolute` to your divs, you must set `z-index` to overlap one above other, initializing your app.

Here there is a idea, how to implement what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/nz2hL6vn/1/

Comment: I had similar effect, this is slightly better tho. However it's still far from perfect. 
Firstly - animation get buggy and the contect from previous slide stays for a second after sliding. 
Secondly - the bottom scroll bar show up sometimes. 

Thanks anyway, gonna try to continue that!